# Invalid regular expression: Invalid group

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a regex with a negative lookahead that detects files which end with `.apk` but not with `-unaligned.apk`. Here it is.

```
/(?s)^((?!\-unaligned).)*\.apk$/
```

However, when I use it in Node (or in the Chrome developer tools, too), it throws:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?s)^((?!\-unaligned).)*\.apk$/: Invalid group
```

I've tested it in [Regex101](http://regex101.com) with a test list of files, and it works perfectly, but after moving to "production" code, it throws an error like that.

Comment: `(?s)` is not valid JavaScript regex syntax.

Comment: @vks This is it. If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it asap =)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I've seen it right after posting it. `(?!s)` removed the error, but only matched a `g`. Anyway, vks had it correct!

Comment: Why a close vote and -1? Maybe if I knew the reasons, an improvement could be done.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Had the exact same problem, regex working fine, but express said it was not.

Comment: @Denny I still wonder, but well, at least with your +1 it's not an ugly negative question anymore! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:(?!\-unaligned).)*\.apk$
```

Try this.Remove the useless group.It is not needed anyways